# Replacing AngularJS Route with UI Router

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to replace AngularJS Route with UI Router since that seems to be what everyone uses. I'm just getting started and am wondering how to replace the following code with $stateProvider:

```
    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        })
        .when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `when` with `state`:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
        url: "/state1",
        templateUrl: "partials/state1.html"
})
```

More details here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: what about the otherwise?

Comment: You just had to click the link, lazy "programmer" :)    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");

Comment: no you're the lazy stackexchanger who wouldn't fully answer my n00b question ;)